# Programmatically Enable/disable input parameters in a QGIS Processing plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

Is there a way to enable/disable a parameter by a checkbox in the processing interface? In my screenshot below, I would like to disable the **Output Wall Aspect Raster** when the **Calculate wall aspect** checkbox is ticked off.

[image: Interface window]

Code is shown below:

```
class ProcessingWallHeightAscpetAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):


INPUT_LIMIT = 'INPUT_LIMIT'
INPUT = 'INPUT'
OUTPUT_HEIGHT = 'OUTPUT_HEIGHT'
OUTPUT_ASPECT = 'OUTPUT_ASPECT'
ASPECT_BOOL = 'ASPECT_BOOL'

def initAlgorithm(self, config):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(self.INPUT,
            self.tr('Input building and ground DSM'), 
            None, False))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterBoolean(self.ASPECT_BOOL,
        self.tr("Calculate wall aspect"),
        defaultValue=True)) 
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber(self.INPUT_LIMIT, 
        self.tr("Lower limit for wall height (m)"), 
        QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double,
        QVariant(3.0),
        minValue=0.0))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(self.OUTPUT_HEIGHT,
        self.tr("Output Wall Height Raster"),
        None, False))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(self.OUTPUT_ASPECT,
        self.tr("Output Wall Aspect Raster"),
        None, False))


def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    outputFileHeight = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_HEIGHT, context)
    outputFileAspect = None
    dsmin = self.parameterAsRasterLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context) 
    aspectcalculation = self.parameterAsBool(parameters, self.ASPECT_BOOL, context)
    walllimit = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, self.INPUT_LIMIT, context)

    provider = dsmin.dataProvider()
    filepath_dsm = str(provider.dataSourceUri())
    gdal_dsm = gdal.Open(filepath_dsm)
    dsm = gdal_dsm.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)

    feedback.setProgressText("Calculating wall height")
    total = 100. / (int(dsm.shape[0] * dsm.shape[1]))
    walls = wa.findwalls(dsm, walllimit, feedback, total)
    wallssave = np.copy(walls)
    feedback.setProgressText(outputFileHeight)
    saverasternd(gdal_dsm, outputFileHeight, wallssave)

    if aspectcalculation:
        total = 100. / 180.0
        outputFileAspect = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_ASPECT, context)
        feedback.setProgressText("Calculating wall aspect")
        dirwalls = wa.filter1Goodwin_as_aspect_v3(walls, 1, dsm, feedback, total)
        saverasternd(gdal_dsm, outputFileAspect, dirwalls)
    else:
        feedback.setProgressText("Wall aspect not calculated")

    return {self.OUTPUT_HEIGHT: outputFileHeight, self.OUTPUT_ASPECT: outputFileAspect}


def name(self):
    return 'Urban Geometry: Wall Height and Aspect'

def displayName(self):
    return self.tr(self.name())

def group(self):
    return self.tr(self.groupId())

def groupId(self):
    return 'Pre-Processor'

def shortHelpString(self):
    return self.tr('Here (shortHelpString()) we can write short information string about this tool.')

def helpUrl(self):
    url = 'https://umep-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pre-processor/Urban%20Geometry%20Wall%20Height%20and%20Aspect.html'
    return url

def tr(self, string):
    return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

def createInstance(self):
    return ProcessingWallHeightAscpetAlgorithm()
```

Comment: From this (old) reply taken from the QGIS Developer Mailing List, this is not possible: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2018-July/053998.html